# Why am i unable to use this simple code in my kotlin repl

Tags: kotlin, range, read-eval-print-loop

I receive this error -----

```
error: incompatible types: IntRange and Int
3..12 -> print("Good fish name")

var fishName = "anyname"
when (fishName.length){
0 -> print("Error")
3..12 -> print("Good fish name")
else -> {
print("OK fish name")
} 
}
```

---

I was expecting to be able to have the message "Good fish name" be printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `when` construct is comparing the argument `fishName.length` which is an `Int` with each of the values in the `when` construct. The first `0` is an `Int`, but `3..12` is an `IntRange`; each must be an `Int` for the equality test.

Here are three solutions:

Pass in a load of `Int`s...

```
    when (fishName.length){
        0 -> print("Error")
        3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 -> print("Good fish name")
        else -> {
            print("OK fish name")
        }
    }
```

or use this alternate form, changing the zero test also to be a range:

```
    when (fishName.length){
        in 0..0 -> print("Error")
        in 3..12 -> print("Good fish name")
        else -> {
            print("OK fish name")
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
From @gidds - "Kotlin lets you mix individual values ... with predicates":

```
    when (fishName.length){
        0 -> print("Error")
        in 3..12 -> print("Good fish name")
        else -> {
            print("OK fish name")
        }
    }
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression

Comment: You don't need a range for 0; Kotlin lets you mix individual values (`0 ->`) with predicates such as ranges (`in 3..12 ->`), as long as the ranges are prefixed by `in`.